# Find the residue of $\sec(1/z)$ at at its poles.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the residue of $\sec(1/z)$ at at its poles.

I know $2/\pi$ a pole and found the limit $\lim \limits_{z\to 2/\pi}(z-2/\pi)\sec(1/z)$ by L'Hospital Rule and it is $4/\pi^2$ is it correct? Is there any easier method? And what about the other poles?

Comment: There are infinite poles, you've analyzed one. It should be $-\dfrac 4{\pi ^2}$.

Comment: Nope its 4/π2...Is there any easier approach?

Comment: You can try to expand $\sec(1/z)$ by Laurent series, but it should be essentially the same as you have to use chain rule.

Comment: @user141456 You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poles of $\sec(z^{-1})=\frac{1}{\cos(z^{-1})}$ are at points $\cos(z^{-1})$ vanishes. So their inverses are $(2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi,(2k+\frac{3}{2})\pi$. Taking L-Hospital Rule you have
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{\cos z^{-1}}=\frac{z_0^{2}}{\sin(z_0^{-1})}
$$
where we used chain rule. Mind that $\sin(2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi=1$ and $\sin(2k+3/2)\pi=-1$. Your derivation is correct. See [the Wolfram Alpha page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue%20of%20sec%28z%5E-1%29%20at%20z=2/Pi).